# How to read css file in Java in xpages

Tags: java, css, xpages, lotus-domino

I would like to read the content of a css file stored in my NSF to include it in the style element in a (HTML) file that I create.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream
```

does not seem to be the way.

Anyone a suggestion?

I tried

```
InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("file.css");
```

and then

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<style>").append("\n");
sb.append(convertStreamToString(input)).append("\n");
sb.append("</style>").append("\n");

static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }
```

which works fine

Comment: I used that a lot of times without problems to retrieve an Inputstream of a properties file located in 'Resources/Files' of the database.
Where do you store the css File and are there any error messages in the server log?

Comment: I guess the reading is not the problem. However I have a stream that I need to convert to a string. toString works not (ofcourse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons IOUtils to copy from the InputStream to a StringWriter and then use toString() on the StringWriter. Here's a simple method that does that:

```
private static String getResourceFile(final String filename) {
    final InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(filename);

    final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(input, writer, "utf-8");
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading: " + filename);
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```